# Generating a binomial distribution around zero

Tags: python, random, numpy, distribution, probability

I'm looking to generate a binomial-esque distribution. I want a binomial distribution but I want it centred around zero (I know this doesn't make much sense with respect to the definition of binomial distributions but still, this is my goal.)

The only way I have found of doing this in python is:

```
def zeroed_binomial(n,p,size=None):
    return numpy.random.binomial(n,p,size) - n*p
```

Is there a real name for this distribution? Does this code actually give me what I want (and how can I tell)? Is there a cleaner / nicer / canonical / already implemented way of doing this?

Comment: i would only see sense in such a distribution if p = 0.5 (otherwise, the notion of centered seems far-fetched)

Comment: Perhaps centred is the wrong word, I mean that the most frequent element should be zero.

Comment: so basically a binomial such as f(0) = max(f(x)). What are you doing with that ?

Comment: Testing out a theory I have for my steganography paper :P.

Comment: `n*p` is the mean of the binomial distribution. The most frequent element is the mode, and [according to wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Mode_and_median) it is either `floor((n + 1)p)` or `floor((n + 1)p) − 1`

Comment: @jhoyla I have a similar task to what you did here. Is there an analytic form of this?

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing is fine if you want a "discretized" normal distribution centered around 0. If you want integer values, you should round `n*p` before subtracting.

But the [limit of the binomial distribution is just the normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation) when `n` becomes large and with `p` bounded away from 0 or 1. since `n*p` is not going to be an integer except for certain values, why not just use the normal distribution?

Comment: This the all true for large N, but the op might want a binomial with a small N, in which case the normal distribution would not be a good approximation.

Comment: Good call on the rounding of `n*p`.

Comment: @AndrewMao Could you elaborate a bit on what you mean by rounding $n*p$ before subtracting in order to get "discretized" normal distribution?

Comment: @Alex if you want an integer-valued support `..., -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ...` instead of real-valued ones that are oddly shifted like `..., -1.714, -0.714, 0.286, 1.286, ...`. Of course, the mean of this adjusted distribution will not be 0.

Answer (score 2):

The probability distributions implemented in the `scipy.stats` module allow you to shift distributions arbitrarily by specifying the `loc` keyword in the constructor. To get a binomial distribution with mean shifted close to 0, you can call

```
p = stats.binom(N, p, loc=-round(N*p))
```

(Be sure to use an integer value for `loc` with a discrete distribution.)

Here's an example:

```
p = stats.binom(20, 0.1, loc=-2)
x = numpy.arange(-3,5)
bar(x, p.pmf(x))
```

[image: bar plot]

**Edit:**

To generate the actual random numbers, use the `rvs()` method which comes with every random distribution in the `scipy.stats` module. For example:

```
>>> stats.binom(20,0.1,loc=-2).rvs(10)
array([-2,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1, -1,  1,  2,  0])
```

Comment: I'm actually looking for a list of random numbers that conform to a distribution, not just what the distribution looks like. I suppose I could generate the numbers from the distribution but that doesn't feel  clean.

Comment: @jhoyla Every distribution in `scipy.stats` of course comes with a method to generate the random numbers. See my edit. Why do you think it doesn't feel clean?